# Exercise 9, Section 6.2 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Use the result of Exercise 8 to prove that, if $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices over the field $F$, then $AB$ and $BA$ have precisely the same characteristic values in $F$.

**My attempt:** We claim $\det (I-AB)=0_F$$\iff$$\det (I-BA)=0_F$. Proof: By [exercise 8 section 6.2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4568243/861687), $I-AB$ is invertible$\iff$$I-BA$ is invertible. By theorem 4 section 5.4, $\det (I-AB)=0_F$$\iff$$I-AB$ is not invertible$\iff$$I-BA$ is not invertible$\iff$$\det (I-BA)=0_F$. Our desired result.

We need to show $c\in F$ is eigenvalue of $AB$$\iff$$c\in F$ is eigenvalue of $BA$, i.e. $\det (cI-AB)=0_F$$\iff$$\det (cI-BA)=0_F$. If $c=0_F$. By theorem 3 section 5.3, $\det (0_FI-AB)=\det (-AB)=\det (-BA)=\det (0_FI-BA)$. Thus $\det (0_FI-AB)= \det (0_FI-BA)$. If $c\neq 0_F$. $(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $\det (cI-AB)=0_F$. By elementary property of determinant, $\det (cI-AB)=\det [c(I-c^{-1}AB)]=c^n \det (I-c^{-1}AB)=0_F$. Which implies $c^n=0_F$ or $\det (I-c^{-1}AB)=0_F$. Since $c\neq 0_F$, we have $c^{n}\neq 0_F$. So $\det (I-c^{-1}AB)=0_F$. By above claim, $\det (I-c^{-1}BA)=0_F$ (since $M_{n\times n}(F)$ is [linear algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4519932/861687) over $F$). Multiply both side by $c^n$, we have $c^n \det (I-c^{-1}BA)=\det [c(I-c^{-1}BA)]=\det (cI-BA)=0_F$. Thus $\det (cI-BA)=0_F$. $(\Leftarrow)$ Conversely suppose $\det (cI-BA)=0_F$. Proof is similar to $(\Rightarrow)$. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: I think your proof is fine. I have not seen the book you are referring to, but it seems to me that the simplest observation is that characteristic polynomial of AB is the same as BA that is $det({\lambda}I -AB) = det({\lambda}I=BA)$. The proof is very similar to the first part of your "attempt". Once you have this the rest is kind of obvious, and, as a bonus, you get things like $tr(AB) = tr(BA)$ etc.

Comment: I agree with Salcio. You may also have a look at [Do matrices $ AB $ and $ BA $ have the same minimal and characteristic polynomials?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311342)